# Подключение к БД с шифрованием

Tags: c#, ms-access

Никак не могу подключиться к бд с шифрованием. Уже и менял способ шифрования, и устанавливал всякие разные вещи с сайта микромягких, но никак. Без пароля подключается. Ms access 2010.

```
String conn_string = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=путь\\бд.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=пароль;";
```

Comment: то есть у вас БД не запаролена, но вы не можете к ней подключиться с паролем?

Comment: @tym32167, нет, я не могу подключиться когда бд запаролена стандартным шифрованием, пишет "it may not be a database that your application recognizes or the file may be corrupt". Без шифрования все подключается.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что база у вас обычная, без шифрования. А вы пытаетесь установить защищенное (зашифрованное) соединение?

Comment: @cauf не совсем так. Я пытаюсь подключиться к зашифрованной базе через запрос выше, но подключение не работает. С той же базой без шифрования и запросом без пароля подключается.